# jquery Requested JSON parse failed when parsing $get argument

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Jquery has is working before the following line is changed

```
data: "ID=1",

$ID=$_GET["ID"]
$array=array("$ID",'B',"C");
```

from

```
data: "",

$array=array('A','B',"C");
```

my ajax file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <button class="ajax_action">click</button>
    <script>
    $('button.ajax_action').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: "test.php",
            data: "ID=1",
            type: 'POST', 
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var name=data[0];
                target.html(name);
                target.attr('disabled', 'disabled')
            },
               error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                    alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                    alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                    alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
                } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                    alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
                } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                    alert('Time out error.');
                } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                    alert('Ajax request aborted.');
                } else {
                    alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                }
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

php file test.php (same dir with ajax file)

```
<?php
    $ID=$_GET["ID"]
    $array=array("$ID",'B',"C");
    echo json_encode($array);
    ?>
```

How to make this work with $_GET["ID"], I need to do action according to the ID which is variable according to the product user chosen

---

and I've read through manual, long ago however manual is ain't easy for a newcomer you know. "You should read manual, idiot" is the worst answer I've ever heard and I can answer every question I don't know with this sentence. @tereško

further changed to following line but still ain't working,

```
    data: {'ID':1},
    type: 'POST', 

<?php
$ID=$_POST["ID"]
$array=array("$ID",'B',"C");
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Comment: `type: 'POST',` would not seem to go well with `$ID=$_GET["ID"]`.

Comment: I'm quite new to ajax

Comment: Well, to begin with, `$_POST["ID"]` works better for posts. Besides that, I'm a bit unsure what you're attempting to do, so I'll leave that to the AJAX experts to answer ;)

Comment: however changing it to type "GET" not working too

Comment: you could also read the manual entry for jquery's ajax wrapper and see how you are supposed to pass parameter .. instead of making shit up.

Comment: why there is a vote down, is it my question too unclear or what. Or too simple please answer me

Comment: I'm following http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/node/107 and I tot this is a place for asking help?

Comment: Are you aware that `language="javascript"` has not been a valid syntax for including JS since some time around 2000th? Also, please, read the fine manual: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: [**And please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**warning**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: had readen through the manual however manual is not so friendly for pure new beginner, php manual is availabe for me though

Comment: I've been using new mysqli for a long time already, thats the post im referring to how to use ajax as quite clear tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using POST instead of GET . On test.php you need to change your php code to

```
<?php
 $ID=$_POST["ID"];
 $array=array("$ID",'B',"C");
 echo json_encode($array);
 ?>
```

Comment: doing this with POST will have to declare a form, however I'm hoping to do it with php?ID=1

Comment: @NgHengLim `POST` data doesn't have to come from a `<form>`; that's what the `data:` option replaces. But, if you want the `data` in the query-string, use `type: 'GET'`.

Comment: its still not working changing my php code to  $ID=$_POST["ID"];

Comment: Code you post the exact error you are getting ? ,it could be something totally unrelated to that code block

Comment: I figure out what happened, i've left out a ';'

Answer (score 0):

Change the type in ajax call to `type: 'GET'`

Comment: instead of `var name=data[0];`  use `var name=JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: its still not working, the php code tried for $_post and $_get also not working

Comment: or you could give a link for me? tutorial or whatever highly related